# Bigquery: Resources exceeded during query execution caused by Order by

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to order a big table using Google Bigquery and the query is :

```
-- standard query
SELECT
  *
FROM
  kaggle_bank_raw.cleaned_train
ORDER BY
  ncodpers
```

and it generates the `query: Resources exceeded during query execution` error.

The table size is 4.28 GB and has 13,647,309 rows.

How can I order a giant table?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can drop the `ORDER BY`, it will likely make your query faster and scale better as the data size increases. The partial ordering produced by 'ORDER BY ... LIMIT' is sufficient for many scenarios.

Comment: but I want a fully ordered table.. how can I order the giant table?

Comment: That's not supported yet.

Comment: @reprogrammer thank you for letting me know. are they going to add this feature soon?